# find the volume of the solid between regions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid between the surface, $z=x^2+xy^2$ and the region in the $xy$-plane is bounded by $y=-x+2$, $y=2x$, and $y=\frac{x}{2}$.

I know that this is going to be a triple integral

I also know that since it is on the $xy$ plane that $z\geq0$.

I don't understand how to set up the integral with 3 different boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

The region is shown below:

[image]

Your integral can splited in tow parts, one for each region described above.

$$I=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 0\leq x\leq 3/4,\ 2x\leq y\leq x/2\},$$
$$II=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 3/4\leq x\leq 2,\ 2x\leq y\leq 2-x\}.$$

Since, $x,y\geq0$ if $(x,y)\in I\cup II$, then $x^2+xy^2\geq0$, thus, the required volume is
$$V=\iint_I(x^2+xy^2)\,dA+\iint_{II}(x^2+xy^2)\,dA.$$

Comment: What software did you use to make such a beautiful diagram?

Comment: @zugzug The Geogebra, it is a free software and it is very intuitive to use!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The volume will be given by $\int\int\int dV=\underset{R}{\int\int} x^2+xy \, dA$, where $R$ is the region in the $xy$ plane described above. It's extremely helpful to draw the region. After looking at the shape (a triangle), you will notice that whether you pick $dydx$ or $dxdy$, this cannot be solved with one double integral. This is because the upper inner function is piecewise. By this, I mean you either have $\int_a^b \int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}x^2+xy\,dydx$ or $\int_a^b \int_{g_1(y)}^{g_2(y)}x^2+xy\,dxdy$, where the function $g_2$ is piecewise.

Therefore, you have to look at the diagram and find out where the upper inner function changes. At that point, you split it up as two iterated integrals.